# Setting GTK2 theme for root

Tags: root, xfce, gtk, theme

When using `sudo`, applications do not follow the GTK2 theme and font. How can I set identical settings for use when an application is run from root, but while inside a desktop from a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `.gtkrc-2.0` file inside `/root`, such as

```
gtk-theme-name="Redmond"
gtk-icon-theme-name="hicolor"
gtk-font-name="Sans 10"
```

Or, can install an utility like `lxappearance` and run it with sudo, then you can set the theme graphically.

Comment: Should the user account have this file somewhere? I think I could symlink or copy the file to the root folder, however, I do not see a hidden `.gtkrc` file anywhere in the user account. How are these settings stored for a user account?

Comment: In the user account you also have a `.gtkrc-2.0` in your HOME directory.

Comment: There is no `.gtkrc-2.0` file in my home directory of the user account, yet I have a custom theme set. Does XFce4 store this information differently?

Comment: I think so, probably it stores the GTK configuration in another form. Anyway, you can just use `lxappearance` to create a .gtkrc-2.0 file.